# Session lost after form submit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, session

The session I set is lost after the form is submitted.

I had built the session class to set new session, unset and so on. In function.php of wordpress template.

### function.php

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
include get_template_directory() . "/custom/session.php";
```

### Session.php

```
class session {
    function __construct() {

    }

    function set_flashdata($name, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    function flashdata($name) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
            $str = $_SESSION[$name];
            return $str;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function userdata($name) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
            return $_SESSION[$name];
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function set_userdata($name, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    function unset_userdata($name) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to set session as :

```
<?php 
    $sess = new session();
    $sess->set_userdata('sess_name',"some value");
?>
<form action="get_permalink(212);">
    //input buttons
</form>
```

After submit the form it goes to the permalink(212). Then I tried.

```
<?php
    $sess = new session();
    $value = $sess->userdata('sess_name');
    var_dump($value);      //returns false. That means session is lost after form submit. Why?
?>
```

Comment: What host are you using? Some hosts have troubles with PHP Sessions & WordPress. Maybe checkout this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move session start/resume into your Session's constructor.

Like so:

```
class session
{
    function __construct()
    {
        if (! session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
    }
```

Another thing to mention, every time you'll do `new Session` you'll be getting an object of the same functionality working with same global variable `$_SESSION`.

You don't need more than one `$session` object, it would be a good time to look into `Singleton pattern`.

Comment: After refering to singleton pattern and changed design pattern to singleton for my session class. My issues was resolved. But how it solved my error. I am not getting. Is it due to single object of the class?

Comment: Hi @user254153 (would be nice to call you by name). The problem was always due not starting/resuming same session. The fix algorithm was to make sure you are starting/resuming a session every time to enquire Session object, hence the example I gave to move session start/resume into __constructor. Singleton pattern works great here as you want to have a global access to Session object and not create more than one instance.

Comment: Exactly. After singleton I didnot have to make a new object every time I call session.

Answer (score 8):

You have to **call always session_start() for each request**.

The mission of session_start() is:

- Creates a new session
- Restart an existing session

That means, if you have created a session, and you don't call to the method session_start(), the variable $_SESSION is not going to be fulfilled.

**Except**: If in your *php.ini* you have set the option [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) to 1, then, in that case it is not needed to call the session_start() because the variable $_SESSION is fulfilled implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use wordpress global variable for condition that session is set or not something like :

```
global $session;
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
include get_template_directory() . "/custom/session.php";
```

Comment: Why use $session.

Comment: wordpress have  a lot of global variable,so can use any where in wp code.

Comment: Still same issue fo wp_session variable

Comment: You need to use session_start() on session.php within constructor something like this 
 function __construct() {
session_start();

    }

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like `session_start()` is not set at the start of the page that `get_permalink(212;)` refers to.

I have almost no experience with WP itself though, so I might misunderstand the functionality of `get_permalink()`

Answer (score 3):

It might be due to www. at the start of your website domain. Make sure that both of pages use the same structure.

Also I faced with the same issue long time ago when the form sends the data to a secured address (https://)

I hope these two items may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer from @rock3t to initialize session in constructor of class, but every time a class object is initiated, it will go to check for session!

Instead, if you are fine, the simplest way to get access to session is by adding following lines to your *wp-config.php* file before the call to *wp-settings*

```
if (!session_id())
    session_start();
```

This will set/initialize session globally and you won't need to set/check for session_start in constructor of a class.

Thank you.